# Creating 2 columns in 1 data report vb6 (male and female sorting)

Tags: mysql, vb6, wamp

I'm having a problem in vb6 (datareport). I was able to display a report from the following code:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strsql As String
strsql = "select * from student where year='" & txtYear.Text & "' AND section='" & txtSection.Text & "'"
Set rs = cn.Execute(strsql)
If Not rs.EOF Then
Set DataReport2.DataSource = rs
DataReport2.WindowState = 2
DataReport2.Show vbModal
Else
MsgBox "Doesnt exist"
End If
```

But my problem is, in my database I have a column "sex" (male or female). What I want is to display all male students to the left page of the data report, and the female students to the right. Sorry for my english. Thanks in advance.

Note: Im using vb6, wampserver(mysql) as database. I want it on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataReports do not support columns in this manner.  I suggest you consider something else, perhaps the DHTMLEdit control or RichTextBox control where you can "roll your own" reporting with preview.

Alternatively you might be able to perform a transformation query of some sort to produce a Recordset with the rows arrayed as you want them.  Then you could still use a DataReport.